# Android SearchView without using CursorAdapter

Tags: android, android-listview, searchview, android-popupwindow

I want to use Android `SearchView` but, I have a limitation that I can not use Cursor Adapter.

What are the other adapter one can use with SearchView?

My current fallback is to use `ListViewPopUp` but it has it's own issue of interaction with menu and back key.

Comment: "I have a limitation that I can not use Cursor Adapter" -- why? Bear in mind that `Cursor` is an interface, and so you can wrap your own data in something that exposes a `Cursor` if need be. I'll admit that this limitation of `SearchView` and `setSuggestionsAdapter()` seems rather short-sighted on Google's part. Another option would be to fork `SearchView`, creating a modified edition that could work with other adapter types.

Comment: Commonsware have explained pretty well how you can tackle the problem. The easiest solution(basically the addition of a for loop in code) would be to wrap your current data in a `MatrixCursor`(and then use it in the required CursorAdapter).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Commonsware is correct. I ended creating custom views which can support my functionality of using adapter and not cursor adapter.